# Existing Eclipse JSP project, can't add to Tomcat on new machine.

Tags: eclipse, tomcat7

I can't seem to add an existing JSP project to Tomcat since I've moved to my new machine. I've been reading web help for days, seems to be a common recommendation to go into Project > Properties > Project Facets > check Dynamic Web Module. I can't see this Dynamic Web Module, I've followed instructions and added eclipse software to enable this but I still can't see this. [image: Below is a screenshot of the Project Facets]

Any help or advice appreciated.

Comment: Hi @AleksandrM for the response, I'm actually already running Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers, the latest version. On my new Eclipse, I'm running other projects over tomcat its just how to add Tomcat to my existing project that is causing me the issue.

Comment: You don't have `Java` checked, so eclipse doesn't know it is a java project.

Comment: Thanks again @AleksandrM, I've ticket Java now, it got unticked when I was playing with configurations trying to make it work. It unfortunately wasn't the issue.